# How do I obtain slopes on a prediction model that's a curve? And save them as a table

Tags: r, input, calculus, non-linear-regression

So here’s the game plan. I’m trying to take this data set (will be a structure object) below, run a curved regression model through it.
Then, I’d like to take the slope (i.e. the first derivative value for each x) at each point, and save the data table with that slope information in its own column.

input.txt:

```
yval    xval
0.198   0.125
0.18    0.0625
0.126   0.03125
0.078   0.015625
0.066   0.007813
0.03    0.0039065
0.00    0.0
```

script.r:

```
dat <- read.table("input.txt", header=T, sep="\t")
library(drc)
library(ggplot2)

mm <- structure(list(x = dat$xval, y = dat$yval), .Names= c("x","y"), class = "data.frame")
model.drm <- drm (y ~ x, data = mm, fct = MM.2())
mml <- data.frame(x = seq(0, max(mm$x), length.out = 100)) #I actually don't know what length does, and am unsure about this line
mml$y <- predict(model.drm, newdata = mml)

ggplot(mm, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    theme_bw() +
    xlab("x lab") +
    ylab("y lab") +
    ggtitle("dose response curve") +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_line(data = mml, aes(x = x, y = y), colour = "blue")
ggsave("mm.pdf", width = 6, height = 4)

#Need to pass in vector (list) of x, into the derivative of mml's function.
#Output will be a list of corresponding slope values for each of those x's.
#append said slope values to the data frame and save it.

dev.off()
```

Summary: 
Taking data, running regression, taking the slope at each value, then saving the same data with slopes in separate column. The output will be the same table, but with a new third column: the slope associated with each x value. Output must look like:

output.txt:

```
yval    xval    slopes
0.198   0.125   slope1
0.18    0.0625  slope2
0.126   0.03125 slope3
0.078   0.01562 slope4
0.066   0.00781 slope5
0.03    0.00396 slope6
0.00    0.00    slope7
```

The problem is, just how to "get at" that information, and how to resave it are things I dont know how to do properly. Im unfamiliar with how R does calculus for the equation. I can get the equation's constants from summary(), but I have no way to process it.

I am unable to find the right combination of informations (or maybe it’s just the search terms I’m using?). I apologize if some of this seems like incorrect pseudocode, R has been... frustrating to learn, to say the least. Help?

R version 3.2.4
Redhat Linux 4.1.2
Data is borrowed from https://plot.ly/~gwaligroski/15/michaelis-menten-equation
Code adapted from https://rpubs.com/RomanL/6752

Answer (score 2):

I'll bring up this line first, you are creating a data frame that has one variable with a length of 100 that is spaced equally from 0 to max(mm$x)

`mml <- data.frame(x = seq(0, max(mm$x), length.out = 100)) #I actually don't know what length does, and am unsure about this line`

Predict then uses that data.frame to decide which points to predict for, so if you use length.out = 5 it will be a very coarse curve and length.out=1000 will be a very smooth curve.

So instead of predicting for a sequence between 1:max(mm$x) you want to predict for your xval so I would use

```
dat$predicted<-predict(model.drm, newdata=dat["xval"])
```

Which will add another column to your **dat** dataframe with the predicted values.

add

```
 +geom_point(data = dat, aes(x=xval,y=predicted),colour="red")
```

to your ggplot and you should see red dots on your curve at the x points you want.

Note: I'm not great at R so I can't explain why dat["xval"] returns a 1 variable data frame (which you need) and dat$xval returns a vector which doesn't work for predict.

Comment: This is a good start. But what of the first derivative at those points? I can't access the equation easily, and I'm unsure as to how I will be able to a first derivative in the first place based on the geom_line curve. The constants for the inverse polynomial that governs geom_line is  embeded in summary